# Use of Empty methods in class

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

why to create a class with empty methods for example `MouseAdapter` class has various methods which is defined empty. And instead  we can use it as interface and  not as class

Code of `MouseAdapter` is as follows:

```
public abstract class MouseAdapter implements MouseListener{
    public MouseAdapter(){}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){}
}
```

As any of above methods are not defined what is the use of these empty methods and why not we shall use it as interface. My question is not only for `MouseAdapter` class but for all classes which has empty methods.

Answer (score 3):

This allows you to extend `MouseAdapter` instead of implementing `MouseListener` and having to write all those (potentially empty) methods yourself. With an adapter you can just override the methods you're interested in.

Comment: could you please explain any class with empty methods its use as in program.

Comment: @AbdulShameer Examples? Look for classes with `*Adapter` in their name. Its a common practice, to have implementations with empty methods, throughout many APIs, e.g. when you have listeners as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

It simply allows you to implement only the methods you do need. Otherwise, you should also add empty methods you don't need, that would be useless code. By the way, this is all explained in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) (first sentence)... Javadoc is your the programer's best friend.

Answer (score 0):

All those methods are in `MouseListener` since you are `implements` you **must** `override` those methods. If you don't want some action you can keep them as empty methods else you need to implement your logic in particular method.

*Highlighted point*.

> When you use `class A implements B`. You must override all methods in
>   B interface in A class

Answer (score 0):

This kind of structure allows you to choose what methods you want to override. So by extending this abstract class instead of using the interface, you end up with less noisy code, if you only want to use some of the methods provided. You can even choose not to override any method (though this would be pointless) and that would be okay.

So in a nutshell you can say: `implements` **forces** you to override its methods; `extends` **allows** you to override its methods.